# Java Collections: NPE even though no null value was ever added

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, nullpointerexception

I recently got an NPE in a context where I was absolutely sure it shouldn't be possible. The class is used in a very multi-threaded program, so I'm aware that you should expect basically anything to be possible, but still.

So, the class defines the following field:

```java
private final Set<TcpIpConnection> _connections = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

In the whole class, this set is only manipulated in two places:

```java
// some method
  TcpIpConnection tcpipConnection = new ServerConnection(clientSocket, _channels, MyClass.this);
  _connections.add(tcpipConnection);
// some other method
  _connections.remove(connection);
```

So I think you will agree that there's no way a `null` could be added to the set. And yes, the set stays in the class and is never proliferated outside.

But now I have a test case which sometimes fails with an NPE in the following statement, which is the only other statement in the class that uses `_connections`:

```java
new ArrayList<>(_connections).stream().forEach(c -> c.close("Server down"));
```

As you can see, I already prevented a `ConcurrentModificationException` by first creating a local copy of the set as `ArrayList`.

Now the NPE appears for `c`, which must be a value previously added to `_connections` - but how can that become `null`?

To be clear, I'm not looking for a solution - I added `filter(Objects::nonNull)` in the stream (or I could've used `Collections.synchronizedSet()` in the initializer), and it's guaranteed to work now.

How can that even happen? Yes, multi-threaded access can screw almost everything up, but putting a `null` in a collection which wasn't there?

Comment: Stack trace please.

Comment: Copying the set into an `ArrayList` like with `new ArrayList<>(_connections)` does not guaranty that you won’t get a `ConcurrentModificationException`, as that exception may already occur while copying. But: 1. Getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` is not the real problem, getting corrupted data is worse 2. You get corrupted data because you’re modifying a `LinkedHashSet` concurrently. Thinking about thread safety when everything is lost, i.e. when you want to iterate over the set, is way too late.

Comment: @Holger Thx, you're right, my approach to avoid CME is flawed. WIll have to look at that again. However, that doesn't explain how the `null` got in there. You write "you get corrupted data" - but how can I get a `null` in there, when I provably never add a `null`? Even if several threads concurrently call
`_connections.add(tcpipConnection)`
they could never add a `null`, because `tcpipConnection` is locally on the stack and never `null`.

Comment: @user207421 I understand the call for a stack trace, but a) I don't know how to easily obfuscate it to safeguard company data, and b) I'm pretty sure it's of no help here. The actual exception message is `Cannot invoke "<snip>.close(String)" because "c" is null`.

Comment: The null got there because you are violating the usage conditions. Solution: don’t. I don’t see why you think an apparently null value is impossible. Anything is possible when you break the rules.

Comment: @user207421 Thx, ok, could you please elaborate which rule I'm breaking? I never said I'm doing nothing wrong here, I just can't see it. @Holger already pointed out my approach to avoid CME is wrong, but that doesn't explain the `null`. Thx in any case.

Comment: That’s what you get when using mutable objects in way that is not thread safe a) “impossible” values, like spurious `null` b) “impossible” behavior, like infinite loops at a harmless-looking `get` on a `HashMap`, or c) exceptions, which is the most harmless category as it tells you immediately that there’s something wrong. Maybe it helps if I tell you that the `null` was already there before you added an element, which you would never see in a single threaded or a correctly synchronized program.

Comment: “So I think you will agree that there's no way a null could be added to the set.” — Instead of assuming, verify that is the case: `_connections.add( Objects.requireNonNull( tcpipConnection ) );`. Now an exception will be thrown when encountering a null.

Comment: @BasilBourque Well, by Java language specification, the result of the `new` operator cannot be `null`, so that check is really unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Just to explain why null is possible

Below are referencing jdk-21+35

In `new ArrayList<>(_connections)`, which will call
[_connections.toArray()](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/890adb6410dab4606a4f26a942aed02fb2f55387/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L181)
-> [HashSet#toArray()](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/890adb6410dab4606a4f26a942aed02fb2f55387/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java#L375)(as LinkedHashSet extends HashSet)
-> [LinkedHashMap#keysToArray()](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/890adb6410dab4606a4f26a942aed02fb2f55387/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java#L375)(as LinkedHashSet is backed by LinkedHashMap)

```java
    // HashSet#toArray()
    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return map.keysToArray(new Object[map.size()]);
    }
```

as here we can see an Object[] is constructed with length `map.size()`, and this Object[] will be copied to the ArrayList.

```java
    // LinkedHashMap#keysToArray()
    final <T> T[] keysToArray(T[] a) {
        return keysToArray(a, false);
    }

    final <T> T[] keysToArray(T[] a, boolean reversed) {
        Object[] r = a;
        int idx = 0;
        if (reversed) {
            for (LinkedHashMap.Entry<K,V> e = tail; e != null; e = e.before) {
                r[idx++] = e.key;
            }
        } else {
            for (LinkedHashMap.Entry<K,V> e = head; e != null; e = e.after) {
                r[idx++] = e.key;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
```

And above is how we set value to the Object[].
So in a concurrent environment, when we call `HashSet#toArray()`, the map size might be 2, but when we go to `LinkedHashMap#keysToArray()`, the map size could be 1(some thread removed element in between), hence there could be some null element in the Object[]. And vice versa `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` could be thrown.

### Conclusion

**Never assume any behaviour of non thread safe class when working in multi-thread environment, there is 0 guarantee.**

Comment: That’s one possible scenario. However, removals are not necessary to encounter `null`. E.g. the reading thread may read the initial value (`null`) for `head` or `e.after`, missing an update made by an inserting thread while it did already see the updated `size`. In fact, the Memory Model allows to read a non-`null` reference for those fields, followed by reading `null` again in a later read. Highly unlikely, but not impossible…

Comment: Thx, now I understand! I did try to look into the API sources, but kinda get lost ;)
Anyway, this makes it clearer - and I know that I really have to approach this differently to become thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, YOU MUST use a `Collections.synchronizedSet()` in your initializer. But it's not enough : the iterator is not safe.

Manipulating the set that is not synchronized in different threads can mess up (will certainly) the `LinkedHashSet` internal state. (ie. double links between entries, etc.)

A good way is to encapsulate your `Set` into another class and to offer synchronized methods to add and remove a connection and, a least, return a thread-safe copy of the Set.

It could be like this :

```
class ConnectionManager
{
  public static ConnectionManager instance = new ConnectionManager();
  
  private Set<TcpIpConnection> connections = new LinkedHashSet<>();

  private ConnectionManager { } // protection against external construction

  public static ConnectionManager getInstance() {
     return instance;
  }

  public synchronized void add(TcpIpConnection connection) {
      this.connections.add(connections);
  }
 
  public synchronized void remove(TcpIpConnection connection) {
      this.connections.remove(connections);
  }

  // returns a synchronized copy and unmodifiable Set (thanx to Holger remark)
  public synchronized  Set <TcpIpConnection> getConnections() {
     return Collections.unmodifiableSet(new LinkedHashSet(this.connections));
  }
 }
```

Then in your code :

```
TcpIpConnection tcpipConnection = new ServerConnection(clientSocket, _channels, MyClass.this);
ConnectionManager.getInstance().add(tcpipConnection);

// or

ConnectionManager.getInstance().remove(tcpipConnection);
```

and using your stream :

```
ConnectionManager.getInstance()
                 .getConnections()
                 .stream()
                 .forEach(c -> c.close("Server down"));
```

Comment: Thx, that looks promising. However, I learned from another comment above and subsequent Google research, that actually `Collections.synchronizedSet()` doesn't help at all here, because it doesn't synchronize iterators. So perhaps you should edit your first sentence accordingly.
What Java really needs is a `ConcurrentLinkedHashSet`...

Comment: @slarti76 There is no `ConcurrentLinkedHashSet` because maintaining an iteration order would be costly while at the same time dubious, as “insertion order” is meaningless for concurrent insertions. You can use `Collections.synchronizedSet()` but have to remember to use `synchronized(set) { … }` when iterating the set (which includes stream operations. Or revive your copy approach: `_connections = Collections.synchronizedSet(…); … ArrayList<TcpIpConnection> workingCopy; synchronized(set) { workingCopy = new ArrayList<>(_connections); } workingCopy.stream().forEach(c -> c.close("Server down"));`

Comment: @Holger, yes you are right. It's better to return a a copy, a synchronized copy. Il will modify my example.

Comment: Thx a bunch everyone!

Comment: @slarti76 : "So perhaps you should edit your first sentence accordingly", yes I just did. Thanx for that point too.